# how to import .glb file in blender 2.80 beta using python api?

Tags: python, scripting, import, gltf

I want to import a model of bench in .glb format using python inside blender.

What function am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GLB is the binary form of the glTF format, and the importer (2.80 and higher, or 2.79 with manual install) can handle GLB filenames directly.

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath='path/to/myFile.glb')
```

Comment: Thank you so much.This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Blender uses the gltf naming, the import operator is [`bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.ops.import_scene.html#bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf)